# IBM Cloud custom domain: Not able to upload SSL certs

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, ibm-cloud

I have tried self-signed certificate, certificate chain ... etc but uploading SSL certificates to IBM Cloud just doesn't work! All I get is the "Internal Server Error", I don't know what to make of it. Anyone who has got it working recently pl. reply back here.

I created certificate as under

```
winpty openssl req -new -x509 -sha256 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout testjeetcom.key -days 365 -out testjeetcom.pem

Country Name (2 letter code) [AU]:US
State or Province Name (full name) [Some-State]:Kansas
Locality Name (eg, city) []:Overland Park
Organization Name (eg, company) [Internet Widgits Pty Ltd]:Personal
Organizational Unit Name (eg, section) []:Pers
Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name) []:test.jeet.com
Email Address []:jeet@dummy.com
```

All I get is the below error

[image: useless_internal_server_error]